# Does deleting row from view delete row from base table - MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Deleting a row from a view, will it delete the appropriate rows from the base tables that the view was created upon? I am using MySQL.

Comment: given that the two answers completely contradict each other, why not try testing this out yourself to see what happens. copy the data to a new db or table, set up the view, and delete the rows.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840494/does-deleting-row-from-view-delete-row-from-base-table-mysql

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it will. The only thing to watch out for, is permissions.

Quoting [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html)

> Some views are updatable. That is, you
>   can use them in statements such as
>   UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update
>   the contents of the underlying table.
>   For a view to be updatable, there must
>   be a one-to-one relationship between
>   the rows in the view and the rows in
>   the underlying table. There are also
>   certain other constructs that make a
>   view nonupdatable.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted a view and lost my entire User table. I have a recent back up but for some reason it didn't back up the user table, I must have had it unchecked accidentally.

Essentially I have to go manually re-create every account and then edit them to use the User ID of all the content that they had posted on their original account that was deleted.

Pain in the ass. Life tip: deleting a view deletes the table it is pulling data from...