# How to delete a row in 2 tables which has the same id. How to use join

Tags: mysql, sql

DELETE FROM `tbl_usergroups`,'tbl_group' WHERE (`tbl_usergroups`.`tbl_group_GroupID`='tbl_group`.`GroupID') AND(`tbl_usergroups`.`tbl_group_GroupID`=27)

GroupID is a foreign key to tbl_usergroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the rows are 1:1 mapping then you could use a view over the two tables and delete joined row from the view.

See this answer [Does deleting row from view delete row from base table - MYsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840494/does-deleting-row-from-view-delete-row-from-base-table-mysql/1840523#1840523) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the foreign key constraint to cascade on delete, the row in `tbl_usergroups` should automatically be deleted.

Failing that, you'd have to delete that entry first, and then delete the row in `tbl_group` once it is no longer referenced by a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

ITYM

```
DELETE FROM `tbl_usergroups` WHERE `tbl_usergroups`.`tbl_group_GroupID`=27
DELETE FROM `tbl_group` WHERE `tbl_group`.`GroupID`=27
```

> `GroupID`is a foreign key to `tbl_usergroups`

Then the order of the `DELETE`s is important.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM `tbl_group` WHERE `tbl_group`.`GroupID`=27' at line 1

Comment: These are two queries and intended as help with finding the solution, not the solution itself.