# MySQL Grant permission based on column value?

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

I am trying to grant access permissions to a certain user who has 'manager' access.  They are able to `SELECT` and `UPDATE` but only to the people in their own group.  The DB is `redflame` and the table is `payroll`.

A portion of the table is this:

```
+------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+
| Dept | Manager | Name   | Birthdate | Salary |
+------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+
|    1 | Y       | BOB    | 1/1/1     |  50000 |
|    1 | N       | BILL   | 2/2/2     |  40000 |
|    1 | N       | BART   | 3/3/3     |  70000 |
|    2 | Y       | JIM    | 4/4/4     |  40000 |
|    2 | N       | JANET  | 5/5/5     |  50000 |
...
```

I am wanting to only allow `SELECT` and `UPDATE` privileges to the manager but only to his group.  I tried,

```
GRANT SELECT (Dept, Manager, Name, Birthdate),
      UPDATE (Dept, Manager, Name, Birthdate)
   ON redflame.payroll WHERE Dept = '1'
   TO 'Bob'@'localhost';
```

I know that this won't work but how do you implement `Bob`'s permission based on his `Dept`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a View for every department and grant privileges on those.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I got this code to work: `CREATE VIEW Dept1 as SELECT * FROM redflame.payroll WHERE Dept = '1';` and then was able to implement the normal `GRANT` privileges.  I also found a suggestion in another article [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840494/does-deleting-row-from-view-delete-row-from-base-table-mysql) where it states `Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying table.`

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

> Normally, a database administrator first uses CREATE USER to create an
>   account, then GRANT to define its privileges and characteristics.

In you php code when you are adding a new record to payroll table, you must do the following (I am writing in pseudo-code):

```
if((new->Dept == 1) and (new->Manager == 'Y'))
{
      if (user with name == new->Name doesn't exist)
      {
            Create a new user with name = new->Name
            Grant SELECT and UPDATE privileges to the newly created user ON redflame.payroll table
      }
      else
      {
            error: user already exists!
      }
}
```

When you are updating a record in payroll table:

```
if(the record was a Manager and he is updated to non Manager)
{
      DROP USER with name = old->Name
}

if(the record was not a Manager and he is updated to Manager)
{
      if (user with name == new->Name doesn't exist)
      {
            Create a new user with name = new->Name
            Grant SELECT and UPDATE privileges to the newly created user ON redflame.payroll table
      }
      else
      {
            error: user already exists!
      }
}
```

When you are deleting a record from payroll table:

```
if((old->Dept == 1) and (old->Manager == 'Y'))
{
      if (user with name == old->Name exists)
      {
            DROP USER with name = old->Name
      }
}
```

If you have root access to the database, you can create ON INSERT, ON UPDATE and ON DELETE triggers. Then use this logics, writing SQL code. Otherwise, implement it in php.