# Distinct Values but get all the columns

Tags: sql, rdbms

In SSMS we have a view, which is returning distinct columns by the following command,

```
Create View [VIEWNAME] As
`Select distinct [Col1],[Col2], Max(TimeDate) as TimeDate
 from [Table]
  Group By [Col1],[Col2]`
```

I want the column [Col3] as well from the table in view.

I tried the following so far but unfortunately, it didn't work for me

```
Select Distint on [Col1],[Col2] * from [Table]
```

Error: Incorrect syntax near 'on'.

Also,

```
select [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],Max[TimeDate] from [Table]
Group by [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[TimeDate]
```

Error: Column TABLE.Col3 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregated function or GROUP BY clause.

Below is the original table sample.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIq3g.png)

Desired table image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxCsh.png)
Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS.

Comment: Done @Stefanov.sm

Comment: Added Images of original and desired table @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on` in Postgresql.

```sql
select distinct on (col1, col2) *
from the_table
order by col1, col2, timedate desc;
```

I guess that your RDBMS is SQL Server. The query below uses the [SQL server equivalent of Postgresql distinct on ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808854/sql-server-equivalent-of-postgresql-distinct-on).

```sql
select col1, col2, col3, timedate
from
(
 select *, row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by timedate desc) as rn 
 from the_table
) as t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much @Stefanov.sm

Comment: Just a quick question! Can we delete rows in view? I deleted it from the table but still shown in the view. Maybe the view turns to a complex view.

Comment: Accepted the answer already. It will count once my reputation reaches 15(as I am a new user) but the feedback has been recorded. Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778255/msql-delete-rows-from-view) is a good SO thread on deleting rows from a view.